# What does System.Now() return in British Summer Time? Documentation omission?

Tags: apex

As per https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm:

```
now()
**Returns the current date and time in the GMT time zone.**
Signature
public static Datetime now()
```

Presumably, the documentation omitted '*or BST if it's British Summer Time*' (or words to that effect)?

So, in BST, system.now() does not mean system.now()+1, surely.

Comment: I had assumed it's return value was always in UTC :/

Comment: It's GMT always!

Comment: This can't be tested until March 28th (when BST begins in 2021), but presumably a system method that is tied to a generic time zone will not suddenly switch time zones based on an arbitrary governmental policy in a single country.  I think you can rely on it being UTC all year long.  If there's anything wrong with the docs, I would say they should have called it UTC instead of GMT -- which is probably more widely understood and less prone to misinterpretation.

Comment: I believe the logic of Salesforce calling this time zone "GMT" is that UTC is strictly *not* a time zone.

Answer (score 4):

In Salesforce the GMT timezone is equivalent to UTC. I think they call it GMT because they view it as a timezone, which UTC strictly is not. As per [Time and Date](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/gmt-utc-time.html):

> UTC is not a time zone, but a time standard that is the basis for civil time and time zones worldwide. This means that no country or territory officially uses UTC as a local time.

Also worth noting, from that same reference:

> Neither UTC nor GMT ever change for Daylight Saving Time (DST). However, some of the countries that use GMT switch to different time zones during their DST period.

Taking this all together, and as mentioned by @Mohith, this value is always GMT (aka UTC) regardless of date.